# Uploading Node.js app to Bluemix

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud

This is the first time I am uploading a node.js app in bluemix server. However,after pushing it,i get this error.

```
2017-06-04T17:12:12.63+0300 [APP/0] ERR events.js:160
2017-06-04T17:12:12.63+0300 [APP/0] ERR       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' 
eve
nt
2017-06-04T17:12:12.63+0300 [APP/0] ERR       ^
2017-06-04T17:12:12.63+0300 [APP/0] ERR Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
https://lar
issaappnode-noncharismatic-livingness.mybluemix.net/
2017-06-04T17:12:12.63+0300 [APP/0] ERR     at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
2017-06-04T17:12:12.63+0300 [APP/0] ERR     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup 
[as o
ncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! argv 
"/home/vcap/app/vendor/nod
e/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! node v6.10.2
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! get-started-node@0.1.1 
start: `
node server.js`
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR!
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! If you do, this is most 
likely
a problem with the get-started-node package,
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this 
fails
on your system:
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! You can get information on 
how
to open an issue for this project with:
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR!     npm bugs get-started-
node
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, 
you
can get their info via:
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls get-
started-no
de
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional 
logg
ing output above.
2017-06-04T17:12:12.68+0300 [APP/0] ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-
debug.log
```

The server.js contains a simple piece of code. Later on I will add mongoDB and the appropiate routes(get,post etc). But to get there,I first need fix that error. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: can you please add your code here? It looks like your app is trying to reach https://lar
issaappnode-noncharismatic-livingness.mybluemix.net/, but it does not exist.

Comment: All done now. It's working. I made some changes in my code.